# Jetpack Compose -PreviewParameterProvider for WindowWidthSizeClass

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using the `WindowWidthSizeClass` for supporting different screen sizes, I want to create a set of previews for the given sizes using `PreviewParameterProvider<WindowWidthSizeClass>`

Whenever I tried using the provider I created, the previews are not rendered. After doing some research I came up with this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211012768) but it is supposed to have been fixed already and no additional information is shown in the Issues Panel

Here's what I have:

```
fun DualActionButtons(windowWidth: WindowWidthSizeClass, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    when (windowWidth) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> {
            CompactDualActionButtons()
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> {
            MediumDualActionButtons()
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> {
            ExpandedDualActionButtons()
        }
    }
}

class WindowWidthSizePreviewParameterProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<WindowWidthSizeClass> {
    override val values: Sequence<WindowWidthSizeClass> =
        sequenceOf(WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact,
            WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium,
            WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded)

}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DualActionButtonsPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(WindowWidthSizePreviewParameterProvider::class) windowWidth: WindowWidthSizeClass,
) {
    MyTheme {
        DualActionButtons(windowWidth)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code (and added some dummy implementations for the 3 composables) and I get the expected result in the preview pane (all 3 types show up correctly), so the error might be in one of the composables. Are your components previewing correctly if you preview them one-by-one instead of using the @PreviewParameter annotation?

Comment: @Ma3x that is so interesting, I tried just having having some dummy implementation where each composable is just a Text and still no luck, would you mind sharing your snippet?

Comment: I shared it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It seems the `WindowWidthSizeClass.*` equality is not preserved when it is provided through the `PreviewParameterProvider` so then the equality checks fail.

One way to go around this is to wrap the values only for the preview code in data classes (data classes implement equality automatically).

```
sealed class WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(val value: WindowWidthSizeClass) {
    object Compact : WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact)
    object Medium : WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium)
    object Expanded : WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded)
}
```

Then you put these wrapped classes in the `PreviewParameterProvider` instead of the original values

```
class WindowWidthSizePreviewParameterProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<WindowWidthSizeClassPreview> {
    override val values: Sequence<WindowWidthSizeClassPreview> =
        sequenceOf(
            WindowWidthSizeClassPreview.Expanded,
            WindowWidthSizeClassPreview.Compact,
            WindowWidthSizeClassPreview.Medium,
        )
}
```

and access the wrapped value right away when you receive the parameter in the preview Composable. In that way no changes to your actual code are necessary.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DualActionButtonsPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(WindowWidthSizePreviewParameterProvider::class) windowWidth: WindowWidthSizeClassPreview,
) {
    MaterialTheme {
        DualActionButtons(windowWidth.value)
    }
}
```

The preview I get for the below code sample (I only changed the order in the parameter provider, just for testing that it actually works as expected):

[image]

The whole code

```
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.windowsizeclass.WindowWidthSizeClass
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewParameter
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewParameterProvider

@Composable
fun DualActionButtons(windowWidth: WindowWidthSizeClass, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    when (windowWidth) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> {
            CompactDualActionButtons()
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> {
            MediumDualActionButtons()
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> {
            ExpandedDualActionButtons()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CompactDualActionButtons() {
    Text("CompactDualActionButtons")
}

@Composable
fun MediumDualActionButtons() {
    Text("MediumDualActionButtons")
}

@Composable
fun ExpandedDualActionButtons() {
    Text("ExpandedDualActionButtons")
}

// region Preview-only code

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DualActionButtonsPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(WindowWidthSizePreviewParameterProvider::class) windowWidth: WindowWidthSizeClassPreview,
) {
    MaterialTheme {
        DualActionButtons(windowWidth.value)
    }
}

sealed class WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(val value: WindowWidthSizeClass) {
    object Compact : WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact)
    object Medium : WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium)
    object Expanded : WindowWidthSizeClassPreview(WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded)
}

class WindowWidthSizePreviewParameterProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<WindowWidthSizeClassPreview> {
    override val values: Sequence<WindowWidthSizeClassPreview> =
        sequenceOf(
            WindowWidthSizeClassPreview.Expanded,
            WindowWidthSizeClassPreview.Compact,
            WindowWidthSizeClassPreview.Medium,
        )
}

// endregion Preview-only code
```

Comment: This works when you declare the sealed interface `WindowWidthSizeClass` but fails to work when using the `WindowWidthSizeClass` from  [Material3](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/windowsizeclass/package-summary)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun SampleScreenPreview() {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        SampleTheme {
            SampleBackground {
                val windowSize = WindowSizeClass.calculateFromSize(DpSize(maxWidth, maxHeight))
                SampleScreen(
                    windowSize = windowSize,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```